# Allow Existing Users to Add Facebook Accounts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

In my app, users can login with Facebook using the code from this [tutorial](https://github.com/railscasts/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised). The only issue is I want to allow users who signed up for my app the old fashioned way (As in users go to the signup page and input all their data like email, password, etc and don't log in with Facebook.) to be able to connect their Facebook account with their existing account. I haven't seen any questions on this, and I'm wondering how should I implement this.

Omniauthcallbacks Controller

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
  alias_method :facebook, :all
end
```

Comment: what's that old fashioned way?

Comment: As in users go to the signup page and input all their data like email, password, etc and don't log in with Facebook.

Comment: oh so you want users to login with the application form rather then go to the facebook login page. If yes, then it's not possible. You will have to be redirected to facebook login page by omniauth. Its inbuilt functionality.

Comment: No, the problem is users have signed up for my app by going to the signup page, but I want them to be able to connect their Facebook account to their existing account within my app.

Comment: Here's an example. So, let's say you go to my app and signup with the signup form. Then ideally, you should be able to go to the user settings page and add your Facebook account so we can get an oauth token and access token to post to Facebook

Comment: When you signup then devise will auto login that signed up user to your app but not with facebook. Now when you click facebook login somewhere from your app then you will have to be redirected to facebook login screen page for login. Once you submit login details then you are done with facebook authentication and can get tokens.

Comment: @AlexSmith I am also trying to find solution for that ..if you find a solution ,tell me

Answer (score 0):

> The only issue is I want to allow users who signed up for my app the old fashioned way (As in users go to the signup page and input all their data like email, password, etc and don't log in with Facebook.) to be able to connect their Facebook account with their existing account.

Two possible ways:

1. Use the email address to automatically connect an existing account with that email set when a user uses the Facebook registration flow. (“An account with the email address foo@example.com already exists, do you want to connect your Facebook account with it?”)
2. Have the user log in using your login system, and then offer them a “connect with your Facebook account”-button – and then when they authenticate via Facebook, connect that Facebook ID with the logged in user account.

Comment: How would I go about doing this with Devise and Omniauth?